# Broken translations on Post Review History

Tags: bug, status-review, review, moderator-tools, localization

On post review history (moderator pages) some translations not used (but exist in Traducir), other part not in Tradicir sources at all. [Link for developers](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/12664/show-reviews) to look at the following page.

> [image]

Comment: To clarify: It looks like [the string "Post Review History" appears in Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1733), but this currently corresponds to the page title shown in the tab/window title (which is translated, as you can see if you're able to load the page) – it looks like the heading on the page itself is not currently set as translatable, and neither are any of these column headings or the line starting with "for" here (even if identical strings exist in Traducir for strings elsewhere on the site).

Comment: (That said, stuff like `FromSync` probably shouldn't be getting directly displayed anyway, since it's not really comprehensible even to native English speakers. It's just the reason for the review task's creation as specified in the code itself. And that table needs to be "Stacks"-ified. But I think those changes could be made separately from this much simpler fix.)